# Mailjet : Send Cc or Bcc mail with Mailjet Send API

Tags: php, api, send, mailjet

I'm using Mailjet Send API.

I can send emails by using this part ofcode :

```
$body = [
          'Messages' => [
            [
              'From' => [
                'Email' => "$fromm",
                'Name' => "$namee"
              ],
              'To' => [
                [
                  'Email' => "$to",
                  'Name' => ""
                ]
              ]
              'Subject' => "$subject",
              'TextPart' => "$text",
              'HTMLPart' => "$confirmationMail",
              'CustomID' => "AppGettingStartedTest"
            ]
          ]
        ];
        $response = $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $body]);
        $response->success();
        $success=$response->getData()["Messages"][0]["Status"];
```

But if I want to add a Cc or Bcc, like  :

```
 $body = [
      'Messages' => [
        [
          'From' => [
            'Email' => "$fromm",
            'Name' => "$namee"
          ],
          'To' => [
            [
              'Email' => "$to",
              'Name' => ""
            ]
          ],
          'Cc' => [
            [
                'Email' => "$cc",
                'Name' => ""
            ]
        ],
        'Bcc' => [
            [
                'Email' => "$cci",
                'Name' => ""
            ]
        ],
          'Subject' => "$subject",
          'TextPart' => "$text",
          'HTMLPart' => "$confirmationMail",
          'CustomID' => "AppGettingStartedTest"
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

then it does not work anymore. However the documentation seems to stipulate it's the right way :  [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/send-api-v31/)

Any idea how to solve this ?

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work any more"? Did you enable PHP error reporting? Do you have any errors? Warnings? Have you tried an `echo()` on `$cc` and `$cci`, are the values OK?

Comment: This is from the page you provided, "Important: The recipients listed in `To` will receive a common message, showing every other recipient and carbon copy (CC) recipients. If you do not wish the recipients to see each other, you have to create multiple messages in the `Messages` array. "
So, you may need to check the variables $cc, $cci for being a single recipient or multiple ones.

Comment: @MustafaAlAmeen Thanks. I know, what I want is to send ONE email, to one person as `To`, one as `Cc` and a last one as `Cci`, so I don't want to send multiple emails.

Comment: @fpierrat Yes I did echo `$cc` and `$cci` and they are OK.

Answer (score 0):

For properties To, Cc and Bcc, use comma separated recipients instead.

> Optionally, in place of Recipients, you can use To, Cc and Bcc
> properties. To, Cc and Bcc can't be used in conjunction with
> Recipients. The properties can contain several recipients separated by
> comma using the following format john@example.com,
> <john@example.com> or "John Doe" <john@example.com>

Only Recipients accepts an array of recipients with name and email.

https://dev.mailjet.com/email/guides/send-api-V3/